# Spring/Hibernate fails to initialize the EntityManager when using mix of annotations and hbm for entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, entitymanager

I have a Spring/Hibernate project with entities defined using both hbm's and annotations.

When I am trying to deploy the project I get the following error message:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Following super classes referenced in extends not found: hibernate.examples.model.Task
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processExtendsQueue(Configuration.java:1768) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1690) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1426) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    ....................
```

The reason I have to keep using both is because some of the code is legacy and I cannot touch that at the moment. And we have to start using the annotations for creating any new entities moving forward.

This is how I am registering both kinds of mappings into the configuration:

```
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan("hibernate.examples.model", "models");
        em.setMappingResources("Task.hbm.xml");
        em.setMappingResources("HealthTask.hbm.xml");

        final HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return em;
    }
```

The `setPackagesToScan` method scans for all the entities marked by annotations and `setMappingResources` is supposed to take care of the hbm files.

When I comment out the `em.setMappingResources.....` then the project gets deployed without any issues.

Also, the weird part to note is that when I run it as a standalone application i.e. using `public static void main(String[] args)` I do not have any issues working with both kinds of mapping. All the entities get registered and schema gets created.

Here is how I run the project:

```
public class ConceptRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();

        ctx.register(HibernateConfiguration.class);
        ctx.refresh();

        System.exit(0);

    }

}
```

But as soon as I deploy the project, it fails to register the hbm files.

Here are my hbm files:

Task.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="hibernate.examples.model.Task" table="TASKS" abstract="true">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="ID" precision="22" scale="0"/>
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>
        <discriminator column="TYPE" type="string"/>
        <property name="type" type="java.lang.String" insert="false" update="false">
            <column name="TYPE" length="10"/>
        </property>
        <property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="NAME" length="50"/>
        </property>
        <property name="description" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="DESCRIPTION" length="250"/>
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

HealthTask.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <subclass name="hibernate.examples.model.HealthTask"
              extends="hibernate.examples.model.Task" discriminator-value="HEALTH">
        <property name="requestServed" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="REQUEST_SERVED"/>
        </property>
        <property name="requestFailed" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="REQUEST_FAILED"/>
        </property>
        <property name="totalRequest" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="TOTAL_REQUEST"/>
        </property>
    </subclass>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Please let me know if there is any other information that you would like from me..

Comment: You should call `setMappingResources` once. It is a `set` not an `add`. In short the only one registered is the `HelathTask.hbm.xml` because it overrides the previously set values... Instead do `setMappingResources("Task.hbm.xml", "HealthTask.hbm.xml");`

Comment: post your project structure for once

Comment: @M.Deinum I cant thank you enough. It had me stuck for the longest time. Appreciate it.

Comment: Stack Overflow a question and answer site, not a question and solution in question site. Thus write an answer, instead of writing the solution into the question.

Comment: @M.Deinum If you post an answer, I will remove mine and accept yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(dataSource());
    em.setPackagesToScan("hibernate.examples.model", "models");
    em.setMappingResources("Task.hbm.xml");
    em.setMappingResources("HealthTask.hbm.xml");

    final HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    em.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return em;
}
```

As the `setMappingResources` is a setter each call to it will replace the current set of resources. As you are calling it twice in your code only the last one will remain (the `HealthTask.hbm.xml` and the `Task.hbm.xml` will be ignored).

If you take a look at the [`setMappingResources`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.html#setMappingResources-java.lang.String...-) of the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` you will notice it takes a `String...` as an argument (a varargs argument to be exact).

So instead of calling it twice call it once with 2 arguments.

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(dataSource());
    em.setPackagesToScan("hibernate.examples.model", "models");
    em.setMappingResources("Task.hbm.xml", "HealthTask.hbm.xml");

    final HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    em.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());
    return em;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot again.